# Why GCLB's default HealthCheck interval is 5 seconds, but NEG's case is 15s?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Google Cloud Load Balancing docs explains the default HealthCheck interval is 5 seconds.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#create_a_health_check

also I found that NEG's default interval is 15 seconds.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/b1d2ea77b79aa08a9de5d80881987ebf79a48876/pkg/healthchecks/healthchecks.go#L47

Why is reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the different native environments. Google Cloud Platform has a default health check interval of 5s. While Kubernetes has a default [pod liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#advanced-liveness-probe-example) check of 15s. The NEG default which you have observed is also 15s to match the pod liveness check, both coming from Kubernetes in this case.